# in which call back function should we call another AJAX call in jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax

autocomplete functionality working when i search the companies.when i select the company i need to call another AJAX call to get deparments which are related to that company.where should i place that call.Is it in onselect or onchange function.

```js
 $("#company").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
       $.ajax({
          url: "findByCompanyName",
          data: {"company": request.term},
          dataType: "json",
          success: function( data ) {
              response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                 return {
                    label: item.company,
                    value: item.company,
                    companyid: item.companyId
                 }
              }));
          }
       });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#eventCompany').val(ui.item.company);
        $('#companyName').val(ui.item.company);
        $('#companyId').val(ui.item.companyId);
    }
});
```

Comment: you code looks good.Have you ever test it?

Comment: why not just use onclick `$("#companyName").on("click",function(e){ e.preventDefault(); //ajax call here})`